# php, ignore value on scraped/echo'd data

Tags: php, xpath, output

Wondering if anyone knows what can be modified with this scraping/output code that spits out values like: +40.07%, in order to ignore certain values. For instance, I already have on my site an automatic "+" being placed in front of every value. However when scraping from that source, it also provides a + in front of positive values, so I'm getting a ++40.07 type of output, when I only want one +. Anyone know what can be added to ignore the outputted + ?

```
    // get sandpdailychange
    function getSandpdailychange(){
    $doc = new DOMDocument;

    // We don't want to bother with white spaces
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    // Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://quotes.wsj.com/index/SPX');



    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = "//span[@id='quote_change']";




    $entries = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
        $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
        //make sure every element in the array don't start or end with blank
        foreach ($ret_ as $key=>$val){
            $ret_[$key]=trim($val);
        }
        //delete the empty element and the element is blank "\n" "\r" "\t"
        //I modify this line
        $ret_ = array_values(array_filter($ret_,deleteBlankInArray));
            
        //echo the last element
        file_put_contents(globalVars::$_cache_dir . "sandpdailychange", 
     $ret_[0]);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve here? Use `intval` on that value.

Comment: Hey Sahil. Well the output of that code is "++0.82%".  That's a scraped value, so in ten mins, it could be "++0.95%".

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of one of the "+"

Comment: One is coming from the scrape, and another is my website automatically is coded to add a "+" for positive values. So, I'd like to remove the one coming from the scrape

Comment: So instead of ++0.95% for ex, I want it to just be +0.95%. If I have some coding on the above example that gets rid of the + coming from the source site, it'll achieve that.

Comment: Just apply intval from the value coming from scrape. http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: thinking it might work using something similar to this, though I've never successfully coded this:  echo str_replace("+", "", $entry->textContent." ");

Comment: Yes, that could be fine. But I think it is better to use `intval`.

Comment: wondering if intval will work though, because remember this data incoming is random every time. it's always a number, but depending on the hour, the values change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147853/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-masteryogurt).